Uniform equivalence of grid functions
I am studying the finite element method and have found a problem:
For a regular and quasi-uniform family of simplicial partitions, prove uniform equivalence
$H^1$ norms of grid functions to the norm:
$$  |u|_{1,h} = \sqrt{|u|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2  + h^{m-2} \sum\limits_{e \in \tau _h} \sum\limits_{k=1}^m(u(x_k^e)-u(x_{m+1}^e))^2}$$
The hint says about using the canonical simplex $e_0$.
I'm know that if $x  = G_e y + b$ then we have $|u|^2_{L_2(e)} = |\det G_e||u|^2_{L_2(e_0)}$ and we can try do smth like :
$$ |\det G_e||u|^2_{L_2(e_0)} +  \sum\limits_{k=1}^m(u(x_k^e)-u(x_{m+1}^e))^2 =  |\det G_e||u|^2_{L_2(e_0)} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^m(|\det G_y | \int\limits_0^{y_k}[G^{-1}_yu']_mds)^2$$
Also i have: $\det G_y = \frac{mes(e)}{mes(e_0)}$ and estimates: $\frac{\rho^m h^m}{(\sigma \nu)^{-m}} \le mes(e) \le \rho^m h^m$ and $||G^{-1}_y|| \le \frac{\sigma \nu \rho}{h}$, where $\sigma, \rho, \nu - consts$.
After that, I have no ideas. I tried to use Cauchy's inequality, but it only turns out to be an upper bound, and anyway my constants will depend on h...
Any suggestions?

It looks like you are on the right tracks, this is basically all answered by scaling arguments. The paper "An a posteriori error indicator for discontinuous Galerkin
approximations of fourth-order elliptic problems" by E. Georgioulis shows some examples of scaling arguments with nodal evaluations. Also Brenner and Scott's book on finite elements gives a good exposure of scaling arguments. By the way, what is the index m here?

Do you mean the affine functions by grid functions? If so $u(y)-u(x)=Du(y-x)$ and as hint suggested calculate in $e_0$ so that you can get the harder direction easier. Then use your estimates between $e, e_0$ to conclude.
